# How to access the variables of a function of a class from another class in Java

Tags: java, android

**CustLatLongCoOrdinates.java**

```
public class CustLatLongCoOrdinates extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    String lat;
    String provider;
    String srcLatitude;
    String srcLongitude;
    protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        srcLatitude=location.getLatitude()+"";
        srcLongitude=location.getLongitude()+"";
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

---

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);


    }
}
```

---

**What i am trying to do**::

How to access `srcLatitude` & `srcLongitude` of class `CustLatLongCoOrdinates`. from the `oncreate` method of `SplashActivity` class

---

**what i have tried**::

```
 public class SplashActivity extends Activity {


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

                CustLatLongCoOrdinates obj=new CustLatLongCoOrdinates();
                obj.onLocationchanged().srcLatitude;

        }
    }
```

- I am not able to do this `obj.onLocationchanged().srcLatitude;`
- Is this possible ?

Comment: Make the variables protected static. Then access them like `MainActivity.myVariable`

Comment: you can make getters and setters for the variables.

Answer (score 1):

you can not, variables in the function are having limited scope to the functions body.

try making that as class level variable(and accessible)

Comment: What is meant my class level variable ? .... i have made those variables global .... do you mean by making them global ?

Comment: Make the variables protected static

Comment: @Casper - Your variables are at "instance" level. Class level means making them static.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton which holds the srcLatitude and srcLongitude members and update them from whatever class you need. Or your LocationListener should probably be a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
String srcLatitude;
String srcLongitude;
```

into

```
public String srcLatitude;
public String srcLongitude;
```

In class `CustLatLongCoOrdinates`
and then access it like:

```
CustLatLongCoOrdinates obj=new CustLatLongCoOrdinates();
obj.onLocationchanged()

/* Access them here */
obj.srcLatitude;
obj.srcLongitude
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the two variables as public static String srcLatitude,srcLongitude;

Then access it in SplashActivity.java as......

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity 
{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);
           CustLatLongCoOrdinates.srcLatitude;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access like this

```
CustLatLongCoOrdinates obj=new CustLatLongCoOrdinates();
obj.srcLatitude;
```

but Some time you will get null value as a result.

if the variables declared with static keyword then it will keep the last changed value. kindly check the below.

```
public static String srcLatitude;
public static String srcLongitude;
```

in this case you can directly access the variable like below.

`CustLatLongCoOrdinates.srcLatitude` and `CustLatLongCoOrdinates.srcLongitude`

More times it will give you a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Create getter/setter method for `srcLatitude & srcLongitude` in `CustLatLongCoOrdinates` class
and use those methods in `SplashActivity`  class

Answer (score 0):

"srcLatitude & srcLongitude" are having "[default Scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.)"

Thus, if Classes:SplashActivity & CustLatLongCoOrdinates" are defined in the same package then you can use following code:

```
CustLatLongCoOrdinates customCoordObject=new CustLatLongCoOrdinates();
customCoordObject.srcLatitude;
customCoordObject.srcLongitude;
```

Else, use below code:

//Change the access modifier to "public" in Class: CustLatLongCoOrdinates

```
public String srcLongitude;

public String srcLatitude;
```

//And then in "Classes:SplashActivity" write following code:

```
CustLatLongCoOrdinates customCoordObject=new CustLatLongCoOrdinates();
    customCoordObject.srcLatitude;
    customCoordObject.srcLongitude;
```